# Multiple Length Value in Database, Query SQL for most LIKELY MATCH

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have found myself stuck and looking for guidance in completing the build of my SQL / PHP Query.

I would like to take the Defined number defined below in $CC_P3 and query it in the PREFIXES table, then return the CATEGORY Column Value of which it most closely MATCHES.

The problem I am having is the PREFIX lengths are different. 
Could any body give me direction in where and what I should be searching or doing to achieve this result?

The PREFIXES table has 3 Columns:

```
    ID, PREFIX, CATEGORY
    1, 0112, A
    2, 0761, B
    3, 0762, B
    4, 0764, C
    5, 0112554, D
    6, 01522, E
```

Part of source code:

```
    $CC_P3 = "0762213311";
    $CC_QUERY = "SELECT CATEGORY from prefixes WHERE PREFIX LIKE '".$CC_P3."'";
    $RESULT = $conn->query($CC_QUERY);
    while($row = $RESULT->fetch_assoc()) {   
        $R_CAT = "{$row['CATEGORY']}"; 
    }
    echo $R_CAT;
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want `like`

```
SELECT p.CATEGORY 
FROM prefixes p
WHERE ? LIKE CONCAT(PREFIX, '%');
```

Note that `?` is a placeholder for a *parameter* holding the value for `$CC_P3`.  Don't munge query strings with such values.  Learn to use parameters.

Comment: Great, I am looking into this now.

Comment: So that i understand you, would this be correct?

`$CC_QUERY = "SELECT p.CATEGORY from prefixes p WHERE '".$CC_P3."' LIKE CONCAT(PREFIX, '%');`